# Powershell: How to get and export NTFS Permissions

Tags: powershell, permissions, file-permissions, acl, ntfs

I currently have been using the following script to get NTFS Permissions. The issue is that when it comes to larger shares, it is very RAM intensive.

```
# Root Share or Root path​
$RootShare = '<\\Share>'
# Gathering files and Directories
$Tree = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootShare -Recurse 
# Gathering NTFS permissions for the RootShare
$NTFS = Get-NTFSAccess -Path $RootShare
# Adding Files and SubDirectories NTFS Permissions
$NTFS += foreach ($Item in $Tree)
 { 
    #excluseInherited for a concise report
  Get-NTFSAccess -Path $Item.FullName #-ExcludeInherited #or -ExcludeExplicit
 }
# Export result to a file

$NTFS | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\File.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

The issue is regarding larger shares, this is very RAM intensive. I have tried other methods such as appending ACL's to a CSV but I usually run into the same issue. This is because of `$NTFS += foreach ($Item in $Tree)` as I believe it just adds to the variable, and will not export until it has recursively finished.

Comment: [Performance-related](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/242404/88771).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the pipeline consequently and avoid temporary variables to keep memory footprint low. As an added benefit, the code becomes more concise.

```bash
# Root Share or Root path​
$RootShare = '<\\Share>'

# Start a scriptblock to group commands which are piped to Export-Csv
& {
    # Gathering NTFS permissions for the RootShare.
    # -> becomes implict output of the scriptblock
    Get-NTFSAccess -Path $RootShare

    # Gathering files and Directories. By piping Get-ChildItem
    # to Get-NTFSAccess we save another temporary variable.
    # -> becomes implict output of the scriptblock
    Get-ChildItem -Path $RootShare -Recurse |  
        Get-NTFSAccess #-ExcludeInherited #or -ExcludeExplicit

} | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\File.csv' -NoTypeInformation
    # Here we are piping the output of the scriptblock to Export-Csv
```

Comment: This worded incredibly. Is there a way to format this in such a way so that it doesn't return "BUILTIN\Administrators", or other properties? Would that require a loop?

Comment: @Shepard I don't have `Get-NTFSAccess` available so I don't know what its output is. In general you could insert a `| Where-Object { condition }` before `| Export-Csv` for filtering. If you need more help I suggest to write a follow-up question.